# Why static array working

Tags: c, linux

I am C-programmer and using

> gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3

on which static array as follow is working

```
int i=10;

int a[i];
```

---

its working fine but according to me it should give error on this type of array declaration,
can any body tell me what is this behavior??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - according to [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), section 6.7.5.2, part 2, static arrays cannot be declared with variable length:

> Only an ordinary identiﬁer (as deﬁned in 6.2.3) with both block scope or function prototype scope and no linkage shall have a variably modiﬁed type. **If an identiﬁer is declared to be an object with `static` storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.** (emphasis added)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i = 5;
int a[i]; // <<== ERROR - this does not compile
```

([demo showing this error](http://ideone.com/AO8hGi))

For non-static arrays (e.g. arrays in the automatic storage area, also known as "stack"), this is allowed. Moreover, you could even pass `i` from outside of your function:

```
void test(int i) {
    int a[i]; // C99 allows this; gcc allows this in c90 as well.
}
```

[gcc allows variable length arrays in C90 as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing C99 standard its helpfull

Answer (score 2):

It's standard behaviour for C99 and later.
Those are called VLA (Variable Length Arrays).

Apparently you are using a C compiler more modern than you expected :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=10;
int a[i];
```

This is valid at block scope (i.e., inside a function) but it is invalid at file scope (i.e., outside the function body). At block scope, it is called a variable length array and it is a feature introduced by C99.